# Camera confirmation changes to portrait from landscape

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

I have an app that is using the standard `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to request an image be captured. When the device is in landscape orientation, the preview is also in landscape, but when the image is captured there's an intermediate confirm/retake screen (built-in, it seems). This intermediate step shows the just-captured image in *portrait* rather than landscape, even though the data comes to me in landscape after confirming.

I've tested this with the built-in camera apps on 5.1 and 4.4.4 with equivalent results.

I had previously used a custom camera implementation to fix this, but I reverted back to this intent workflow to preserve much of the built-in behavior I didn't want to have to replicate.

Is there some intent flag or other setting I can use to signal that the orientation should somehow remain the same or do I have to use my own camera implementation to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tested this with the built-in camera apps on 5.1 and 4.4.4 with equivalent results.

There are thousands of Android device models. They ship with hundreds of different "built-in camera apps". Each of these apps can handle `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` how it wants to, and some of those apps have bugs or undesired behavior.

> I reverted back to this intent workflow to preserve much of the built-in behavior I didn't want to have to replicate.

There is no "built-in behavior" that is guaranteed across all of the different possible camera apps.

> Is there some intent flag or other setting I can use to signal that the orientation should somehow remain the same

No.